# Not live long enough with CSV and dataflow

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    timely::execute_from_args(std::env::args().skip(0), move |worker| {

        let (mut input, probe) = worker.dataflow::<_, _, _>(|scope| {
            let (input, data) = scope.new_collection();
            let probe = data.inspect(|x| println!("observed data: {:?}", x)).probe();

            (input, probe)
        });

        let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
            .has_headers(false)
            .flexible(true)
            .delimiter(b'\t')
            .from_reader(io::stdin());

        for result in rdr.deserialize() {
            let record = result.expect("a CSV record");

            let mut vec = Vec::new();
            for i in 0..13 {
                vec.push(&record[i]);

            }

            input.insert(vec);
        }
    });
}
```

The error is record can not live long enough. I try to read the CSV record and read it as a vector. Then insert records in to the data flow.  I can run them separate. I can read the CSv as vector and use the data flow in other place.

Comment: What did you expect? What kind of error has occurred?

Comment: I want to use the differential dataflow for the CSV file. IT can not run . the error : `record` does not live long enough
  --> examples\main.rs:44:27
   |
44 |                 vec.push(&record[i]);
   |                           ^^^^^^ does not live long enough
...
49 |         }
   |         - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible code sample that other people can run. As it stands, this question leaves out crucial details, such as the type of `record`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are pushing to the Vec a borrowed value: `&record[i]`. The `&` means borrow, and as a consequence the original value `record` must outlive the borrower `vec`.

That might seem fine (both are in the `for` body, and thus both have the same lifetime, i.e., they both live inside the `for` body and therefore none outlive each other), but this doesn't happen because the line `input.insert(vec)` is *moving* `vec`. What this means is that `vec` now becomes owned by `input` and hence it lives as long as `input` (as far as I understand). Now, because `input` is outside the `for` body, the moved `vec` lives as long as `input` and therefore outlives the `record[i]`s.

There are a few solutions, but all of them try to remove the dependency between `record` and `input`:

1. If the `record` is an array of primitive values, or something that implements the `Copy` trait, you can simply omit the borrow and the value will be copied into the vector: `vec.push(record[i])`.
2. Clone the `record` value into the vector: `vec.push(record[i].clone())`. This forces the creation of a clone, which as above, the `vec` becomes the owner, avoiding the borrow.
3. If the elements in the `record` array don't implement `Copy` nor `Clone`, you have to move it. Because the value is in an array, you have to move the array fully (it can't have elements that haven't been removed). One solution is to transform it into an iterator that moves out the values one by one, and then push them into the vector:

   ```
   for element in record.into_iter().take(13) {
       vec.push(element)
   }
   ```
4. Replace the `record` value with a different value. One final solution in order to move only parts of the array is to replace the element in the array with something else. This means that although you remove an element from the array, you replace it with something else, and the array continues to be valid.

   ```
   for i in 0..13 {
       vec.push(std::mem::replace(&record[i], Default::default()));
   }
   ```

   You can replace `Default::default()` with another value if you want to.

I hope this helps. I'm still a noob in Rust, so improvements and critique on the answer are accepted :)

Comment: Thanks,  first one: String cannot use in the vector. It use &str.  2: the erroe is this type don't have this methos.  3: same error: record cannot live long enough. 4: mismathched types.

Comment: What is the type of `input`? If `vec` is a vector of strings, you could also try `vec.push(String::from(&record[i]))`. Also, what are the mismatched types in 4?

Comment: the type of input could be the vec, tuple or just the number which I have test. I'm also not sure, because this is a operator  of  a framework. I think vec only can use for &str. it cannot have string.  Type 4:examples\main.rs:44:44
   |
44 |                 vec.push(std::mem::replace(&record[i], Default::default()));
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
   |
   = note: expected type `&mut _`
              found type `&str`
   = help: here are some functions which might fulfill your needs:
           - .slice_mut_unchecked(...)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to put the code in the comment.T-T

Comment: I have solved this problem. use：insert(*vec),  because insert(vec), vec use the record. record's life finished after push.