# Why do strings from a csv::Reader's records not live long enough when inserted into a HashMap?

Tags: hashmap, rust, lifetime, borrowing

I'm new to the whole lifetime concept of Rust. I'm trying to read some data from CSV files and put them into a `HashMap`:

```
extern crate csv;

use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let files = vec!["file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv"];

    let mut topics: HashMap<(&str, &str), &str> = HashMap::new();
    for filename in files {
        let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_path(filename).unwrap();

        for rec in rdr.records() {
            let rr = rec.unwrap();
            let value1 = rr.get(0).unwrap();
            let value2 = rr.get(1).unwrap();
            topics.insert((filename, value1), value2);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=69038f3368ad65cdcf9304f76d08a480&version=stable&mode=debug)

However the following error occurs:

```
error[E0597]: `rr` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:14:26
   |
14 |             let value1 = rr.get(0).unwrap();
   |                          ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
17 |         }
   |         - `rr` dropped here while still borrowed
18 |     }
19 | }
   | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

I thought insertion into the `HashMap` transfers ownership and thus the records are available also outside of the loop. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this piece of code:

```
let mut topics: HashMap<(&str, &str), &str> = HashMap::new();
for filename in files {
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_path(filename).unwrap();

    for rec in rdr.records() {
        let rr = rec.unwrap();
        let value1 = rr.get(0).unwrap();
        let value2 = rr.get(1).unwrap();
        topics.insert((filename, value1), value2);
    }
}
```

It creates a `HashMap` that contains references to some strings, but what is the owner of those strings? It is `rr`; thus your error message.

Following the code:

1. `Reader::from_path` reads the CSV from disk and `rdr` owns that result.
2. The documentation for [`Reader::records`](https://docs.rs/csv/1.0.0/csv/struct.Reader.html#method.records) says (emphasis mine):

   > Returns **a borrowed iterator** over all records as strings.

   Thus the iterator cannot outlive the `Reader`.
3. [`StringRecord::get`](https://docs.rs/csv/1.0.0/csv/struct.StringRecord.html#method.get)'s API is:

   > ```
   > pub fn get(&self, i: usize) -> Option<&str>
   > ```

   This returns a string reference that only lives as long as `self` does.

By tracing this, the string slices you are attempting to insert actually reference data owned by the `StringRecord`. These records are dropped at the end of the `for` loop's body, as shown in the error message. It would cause memory unsafety to allow you to have these references after the loop, thus the compiler stops you.

Inserting `String`s instead allows the code to continue:

```
topics.insert((filename, value1.to_owned()), value2.to_owned());
```

> I thought insertion into the `HashMap` transfers ownership

Yes, it does. The ownership **of the references** is transferred. The thing  those references refer to is not.

See also:

- [variable does not live long enough when storing a csv::DecodedRecords iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36645452/155423)
- [Not live long enough with CSV and dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45284132/155423)

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is the CSV fields only live as long as the CSV line lives and you're trying to save borrows of the fields into topic that lives longer than the CSV reader.

To do that you need the `HashMap` to take ownership of the CSV fields by copying or moving the fields into the hashmap. To do that you need to use `String`s in the map rather than `&str`s.

This will do what you want:

```
extern crate csv;

use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let files = vec!["file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv"];

    let mut topics: HashMap<(String, String), String> = HashMap::new();
    for filename in files {
        let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_path(filename).unwrap();

        for rec in rdr.records() {
            let rr = rec.unwrap();
            let value1 = rr.get(0).unwrap();
            let value2 = rr.get(1).unwrap();
            topics.insert((filename.into(), value1.into()), value2.into());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to highlight how it differs from the existing answers. As it is right now, it doesn't seem to add anything new.